# Splunk rex extract field, I am close but just cant get it matching

Tags: regex, splunk

Value session_value contains this info:

not found, name: user@mycompany.com more text here

Trying to use this:

```
rex field=session_value ":\s(?<USERID>)@"
```

To extract: user

I think I am close, anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but the most important part is missing.  You need to specify what characters match in the capture group.  For example,

```
rex field=session_value ":\s(?<USERID>\w+)@"
```